# If / else object using @@loop with params gulp-file-include

Tags: gulp

If / else object using @@loop with params gulp-file-include.
can't check for an object inside @loop.

```
 @@loop('html/components/stacked-cards/stacked-cards.html', [
    {
    "stackedCards": {
    "image": "",
    "orderNum": "54674567",
    "titleBox": "شركة الهدى للصناعات"
    }},
    {
    "stackedCards": {
    "image": "/images/section1.svg",
    "orderNum": "54674567",
    "titleBox": "شركة الهدى للصناعات"
    }},

    ])

    @@if (context.stackedCards.image) {
    //test
    } //not working

    Cannot read property 'orderNum' of undefined: (context.stackedCards.orderNum)
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle

Comment: I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-file-include